# Conditionally import locals for improving performance on components

Tags: javascript, internationalization, nuxt.js

Trying to import one language from many other languages in relative path to hinder unnecessary load on page refresh and get better Lighthouse results.

When Vue18i is like this, it loads these 2 languages.

```
locales: [
        {
          code: 'en',
          iso: 'en-GB',
          name: 'English',
          // file: 'en.json',
          file: 'en.js'
        },
        {
          code: 'tr',
          iso: 'tr-TR',
          name: 'Türkçe',
          file: 'tr.js',
          // isCatchallLocale: true
        },
      ],
```

I want it to load one language, and 1 page has a category component with over 200 arrays. Demand to load just one languages category translations conditionally.

For example, the below solution is not good considiring each language arrays and category translations.

```
<i18n>
{
  "en": {
    "hello": "hello world!"
  },
  "ja": {
    "hello": "こんにちは、世界!"
  }
}
</i18n>

<template>
  <p>{{ $t('hello') }}</p>
</template>
```

When Categorizer.vue component opens, when config.baseapi is http://localhost:3000/en/p/add. it should load encategory translations to i18n.

```
import en from '~/locales/encategory.json'
```

If it is http://localhost:3000/tr/p/add, should load Turkish translation.

```
import tr from '~/locales/trcategory.json'
```

Comment: You're using `nuxt/i18n`? Did you tried the `lazy` configuration? https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/lazy-load-translations

Comment: Hi, yes tried already, however it imports every single languages' category file which are over 10kb each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have found a simple way. Couldn't find references because there are many for CommonJS but not for ES6 JavaScript. This is for pure JavaScript optimized, thus for Nuxt. You don't want to load 50 languages for a, let's say a Turkish user:

```
    let productcolortr;
    let productcoloren;
    const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((f) => setTimeout(f, ms));
    if ($locale == 'en') {
            await sleep(4000); // simulate network delay
            productcoloren = (await import('../../../locales/productcoloren')).default;
            addMessages('en', productcoloren);
        } else {
            await sleep(4000); // simulate network delay
            productcolortr = (await import('../../../locales/productcolortr')).default;
            addMessages('tr', productcolortr);
        }
```

This is for new generation Sveltekit implication. It waits before DOM loads and implements the if condition. $lan is store variable, much better here than Nuxt:

```
{#if $lan == "en"}
    {#await import('../../locales/en.js') then c}
    {$lan = "en"}
    {/await}
    {:else}
    {#await import('../../locales/tr.js') then c}
    {$lan = "tr"}

    {/await}
{/if}
```